# Biometrics Fingerprint is giving somebody else's information

Tags: c#, vb.net, biometrics, zkteco

I have this Biometrics, but it gives me the completely wrong output - the different *userid* and the *verify date* at year 2132.

What can be causing such wrong information?
I couldn't find any similar problem on Internet. Does anyone else have encountered the same problem like mine?

---

C# Code:

```
            if (axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(GetMachineNumber()))
        {
            while (axCZKEM1.SSR_GetGeneralLogData(GetMachineNumber(), out sdwEnrollNumber, out idwVerifyMode,
                        out idwInOutMode, out idwYear, out idwMonth, out idwDay, out idwHour, out idwMinute, out idwSecond, ref idwWorkcode))//get records from the memory
            {
                DataRow dr = dt_log.NewRow();
                dr["User ID"] = sdwEnrollNumber;
                dr["Verify Date"] = idwYear + "-" + idwMonth + "-" + idwDay + " " + idwHour + ":" + idwMinute + ":" + idwSecond;
                dr["Verify Type"] = idwVerifyMode;
                dr["Verify State"] = idwInOutMode;
                dr["WorkCode"] = idwWorkcode;
                dt_log.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            ret = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
            ret = idwErrorCode;

            if (idwErrorCode != 0)
            {
                lblOutputInfo.Items.Add("*Read attlog failed,ErrorCode: " + idwErrorCode.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                lblOutputInfo.Items.Add("No data from terminal returns!");
            }
        }
```

---

VB.NET Code:

```
If axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber) Then

            While axCZKEM1.SSR_GetGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber, idwEnrollNumber, idwVerifyMode, idwInOutMode, idwYear, idwMonth, idwDay, idwHour, idwMinute, idwSecond, idwWorkCode)

                Dim newitem As New ListViewItem()

                    newitem.Text = idwEnrollNumber.ToString()
                    newitem.SubItems.Add(idwYear.ToString() + "-" + idwMonth.ToString() + "-" + idwDay.ToString() + " " + idwHour.ToString() + ":" + idwMinute.ToString() + ":" + idwSecond.ToString())
                    newitem.SubItems.Add(idwVerifyMode.ToString)
                    newitem.SubItems.Add(idwInOutMode.ToString)
                    newitem.SubItems.Add(idwWorkCode.ToString)
                    lvLogs.Items.Add(newitem)

            End While
  End If
```

---

> Device Model : MA300
>
> Device Type : Access Control

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That is not how you should construct DateTime objects. Try using [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Globalization_Calendar_) to construct the DateTime object and then calling ToString with your desired format. If that fails then you can rule out that :

```
newitem.SubItems.Add(New DateTime(idwYear, idwMonth, idwDay, idwHour, idwMinute, idwSecond).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))
```

I would also suggest setting up a breakpoint when constructing the DateTime object and inspect the values of idwYear/Month/etc. to make sure that the referenced variables have the expected values.

I double-checked the [documentation for this method](http://desarrollo.zktecolatinoamerica.com/sdk/read_general_log_data) and it looks like the signature is correct. I would also recommend checking that your variables are declared as Integer variables (just to make certain).

Answer (score -3):

The date and time at machine must be wrong.